# Can I use the IF ELSE SQL statement without BEGIN and END?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I notice that it is not necessary to use the BEGIN and END in a IF ELSE T-SQL Statement. So why we need it?

```
DECLARE @abc  int = 1
      , @test int = 3

IF @abc = 1 

   IF @test = 3
   
      SELECT 34

   ELSE 
  
      SELECT 4444

ELSE

   IF @test = 3
   
      SELECT 3

   ELSE 
  
      SELECT 4
```

I get the right results.

Comment: We need it because now you don't know where each block starts and ends. The example's code is somewhat trivial. What if one of the indented blocks contained *two* statements? Just two `SELECT`s, eg `SELECT 34; SELECT 42;` ? Would these be part of the same branch? What if there was no `ELSE` to cause a syntax error in that case?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How you would do it? Puting an Begin and END into each IF ELSE BLOCK?

Comment: `BEGIN...END` allows for *multiple* statements to be in logical flow. Without them only the *immediate following* statement is part of it. So sure, you can omit it, but if you want lots of statements you'd have lots of `IF`s...

Comment: You need begin/end if you have more than a single statement in each branch, ie a statement block. It's [clearly documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#arguments) `To define a statement block, use the control-of-flow keywords BEGIN and END.`

Comment: `IF` and conditional logic is rarely needed in SQL, so yes. In the few cases where I need to use `IF` or the even rarer cases where `WHILE` is needed, I use `BEGIN/END` even for single statements. In actual code those are rarely single line `SELECTs`, they're multiline queries, so `BEGIN` and `END` help clean up the code.

Comment: What is the benefit of leaving it out? You like ticking time bombs, or really hate typing?

Comment: "How you would do it?" Opinion-based; off-topic for SO. Some hate the verbosity, others will argue that a consistent coding style helps prevent disastrous mistakes. Just make sure you and your co-workers agree on a single coding style, to prevent edit wars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is somewhat contrived. What if each branch contained *two* statements, eg `SELECT 34; SELECT 42;`? Or worse, `SELECT 34; DELETE ...;` ?

```
IF @abc = 1 

   IF @test = 3
   
   SELECT 34
   DELETE SomeTable
   WHERE ID>34

   ELSE 
  
   SELECT 4444

ELSE

   IF @test = 3
   
   SELECT 3

   ELSE 
  
   SELECT 4
```

The query compiler sees this:

```
IF @abc = 1 
BEGIN
   IF @test = 3
   BEGIN
       SELECT 34
   END
END

DELETE SomeTable
WHERE ID>34

ELSE...
```

Fortunately, `ELSE` result in a syntax error. Without `ELSE` the `DELETE` statement will get executed unconditionally.

In this case `BEGIN` and `END` are needed to define the block :

```
IF @abc = 1 
BEGIN
   IF @test = 3
   BEGIN
       SELECT 34
       DELETE SomeTable
       WHERE ID>34
   END
END
```

Comment: But I do not need BEGIN and END if I just have one SELECT Statement in the code block?

Comment: @mikey22022 Correct, if you just have one SELECT statement, you don't technically need it. But you should still put it there anyway. It protects you from future code changes and also serves to self-document (e.g. it makes it easier for others to read your code).

Comment: @AaronBertrand something I was reminded of when I added a `PRINT` after `IF @@TRANCOUNT >0` once.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yep, and as much as I try to always be a good example, I’m sure I have a few answers here where I’ve done the same.